# Two references to the same dependency inside single pom.xml

Tags: maven, pom.xml

I have two references to the same dependency inside single pom.xml, one in the dependencies section and another in the configuration of a plugin. Can I avoid this duplication somehow?

```
<project>
    ...
    <dependencies>
        ...
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.example</groupId>
            <artifactId>module</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        ...
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            ...
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.10</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        ...
                        <configuration>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>module</artifactId>
                                    <version>1.0</version>
                                    ...
```

Comment: The problem here is that you simply cut out the important part. Without a full pom it's not possible to say. I have my doubts cause these are two different things. Furthermore do you have a problem with that?

Comment: You cannot avoid the dependency declaration, at least you can use a property or _dependencyManagement_ for its version.